# google places automplete only suggestions with stress number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-places-api, react-google-places-autocomplete

I am working with googles api places for address autocomplete suggestions.
This is my simple working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
   <input id="customerAddress" name="customerAddress" required autocomplete="off" />
   <input id="zip" name="zip" required readonly />
   <input id="city" name="city" required readonly />
</form>

    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initAutocomplete&libraries=places"
      async
    ></script>
    
    <script>

        let autocomplete;
        
        function initAutocomplete() {
         
          autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.querySelector("#customerAddress"), {
            componentRestrictions: { country: ["de", "DE"] },
            fields: ["address_components", "geometry"],
            types: ["address"],
          });
          autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress);
        }
        
        function fillInAddress() {
          
          const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          var address = ""
          var streetNumber = ""
        
          
          for (const component of place.address_components) {
            const componentType = component.types[0];
            
            switch (componentType) {

              case "route": {
                address = component.long_name;
                break;
              }
              
              case "street_number": {
                  streetNumber = component.long_name
                  break;
                }
        
              case "postal_code": {
                document.querySelector("#zip").value = component.long_name;
                break;
              }
        

              case "locality":
                document.querySelector("#city").value = component.long_name;
                break;

            }
          }
        
        document.querySelector("#customerAddress").value = address +" "+streetNumber
                  
          
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I would realize the following situation:

- the customer should write his address into the field "customerAddress" to get the suggestions, but the address have to include a street number. how can I restrict this?
- The form should only be able to be submitted, if the customer selected a suggestions from the autocomplete list. If he / she write manually a address, which doesn't is from the autocomplete list, it has to be an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the best solution would be to have separate hidden input where you would put selected address which you would run validation against, if it is not defined you simply return error.

As for having street number you can also run the validation of selected Place. If it has selected type `street_number` it is valid, if not it's not.

I am not sure if you can disable Google to restricts search results to only addresses with street number.